# Difference between these 2 reduced clauses

Tags: verbs, reduced-relative-clauses

Is there any meaningful difference between these sentences? Are they replaceable in all situations?

> A man who narrated brutal videos has come out of the shadows after ***being captured*** by an American-backed militia.

VS

> A man who narrated brutal videos has come out of the shadows after ***captured*** by an American-backed militia.

Answer (score 4):

Consider:

> The bench looked good after painted. <sup>No</sup>
>
> The bench looked good after *it was* painted. <sup>Yes</sup>
>
> The bench looked good after *being* painted. <sup>Yes</sup>

The past participle alone (here, **painted**)  cannot complement **after**.

But it can complement **when** and **once**:

> The bench looked good once painted. <sup>Yes</sup>
>
> The bench looked good when painted. <sup>Yes</sup>